# How to index a csv file which is tab separated using solr?

Tags: csv, solr

the csv field looks like

Sno   Item   productid   description

10   Camera   92        it is cannon "HD with long focus"

When the csv is indexed in solr the data which is given within ("") cannot be indexed and throws an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried with the method suggested in the [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateCSV#Tab-delimited_importing)?

Tab delimited file could be imported into solr by setting the separator to tab (%09) and the escape to backslash (%5c), like this:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv?commit=true&separator=%09&escape=\&stream.file=/tmp/result.text'
```

Comment: In this case, why would the backslash-escape be needed?

Comment: @John Dunno exactly, this was a long time ago. Intuitively though, isn't it used to tell the parser which character is used to escape tabs in your input file (when you have tabs as a legitimate part of your content and you don't want Solr to treat them as separators). This is generally specified when you're exporting to a file from e.g. Postgre or MariaDb (new MySQL), e.g. `... FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"`